# How can I grab an element inside of an <li> in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `<li>` - there are many of these, but this is just one example:

```
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-d ui-li-has-icon io-sidebar-link io-sidebar-link-standard" data-theme="d" io-sidebar-section="0aa210f2-e811-4bae-aac0-649bf87fb240" io-object-view="/cms?url=ui/object&amp;object=db13a9ad-2494-34bb-8a59-cb99fd308051" io-record-view="/cms?url=ui/record&amp;object=db13a9ad-2494-34bb-8a59-cb99fd308051" style="display: block">
          <img src="/document/423fc17f-08b2-46bb-a1db-a5395cd63b83/latest" class="ui-li-icon ui-li-thumb" height="16" width="16">
          <div class="io-sidebar-link-text">Tasks</div>
        </li>
```

I have a click event bound, and would like to print out the value of `io-sidebar-link-text`. How can I do this?

`$(this).('.io-sidebar-link-text')` is incorrect I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close! Use `$(this).find('.io-sidebar-link-text').text()` inside the click handler.

`$(this).find(xyz)` is syntactic sugar for `$(xyz, this)`; so checkout both the docs for the [former](http://api.jquery.com/find), and the [latter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: its html() or text() , not val() right ? because io-sidebar-link-text its a <div>

Comment: @ric_bfa: Right. My brain was thinking `text`, but my keyboard typed `val`!

Comment: Does "syntactic sugar" mean it makes your CPU work harder, or just that it makes it easier for young developers to swallow?

Comment: @Matt yeah, i do this alot. :)

Comment: @mblase75: `$(xyz, this)` [simply calls][https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.4/src/core.js#L168] `$(this).find(xyz)`, so it'll burn 1 calorie max (never heard it called that btw.. made me laugh :P)

Answer (score 0):

this will select only the li how has the attribute io-sidebar-link-text , and get this attribute's value with the attr()  method

```
var title = $("li[io-sidebar-link-text]").attr("io-sidebar-link-text");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always in a div:

```
$(this).find('div').text();
```

or if you want to select on the class:

```
$(this).find('.io-sidebar-link-text').text();
```